# php shopping cart quanty update with link

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to use links (anchors) to update my shopping cart, not buttons, for example:

```
<a href="shoppingcart.php?command=update&product<?=$id?>=<?=$q?>">update</a>
```

however this does not update my cart. How can I get this to work?

My header:

```
if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['id']>0){
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    sepetle($id,1);
}        
else if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['id']>0){
    remove_product($_REQUEST['id']);
}
else if($_REQUEST['command']=='clear'){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
else if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $id=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$id]);
        if($q>0 && $q<=999){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML code:

```
if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
    echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td>Serial</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td><td>Options</td></tr>';
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $id=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $pname=get_product_name($id);
        if($q==0) continue;
    }
}
```

My links:

```
<a href="shoppingcart.php?command=clear&id=<?=$id?>">Clear</a>
<a href="shoppingcart.php?command=update&product<?=$id?>=<?=$q?>">update</a>
```

My table:

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td><?=$i+1?></td><td><?=$pname?></td>
    <td>$ <?=get_price($id)?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="product<?=$id?>" value="<?=$q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>                    
    <td>$ <?=get_price($id)*$q?></td>
    <td> <a href="shoppingcart.php?command=delete&id=<?=$id?>">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you debug yet, to see where it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is the url, you shouldn't wrap the variables with `<?php ?>` all you need is just put your variable between `'. ... .'` like :

```
<a href="shoppingcart.php?command=update&product='.$id.'">update</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start with nothing in your cart that `$max` variable is going to be zero isn't it? So the for loop will not run and nothing will be added to your cart. It would help to see the URLs your code creates and also any debug output.